# Variable with double underscore cannot be used in class?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
def __g_fun():
    pass

__a = 3
a=3

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global a,__a
        print "locals:",locals()
        print "global:",globals()
        self.aa = __a
    def fun(self):
        return __g_fun()


t=Test()
t.fun()
```

Output:

```
locals: {'self': <__main__.Test object at 0x7f53580d50d0>}

global: {'__g_fun': <function __g_fun at 0x7f53580c52a8>, 'a': 3, '__a': 3, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'test.py', '__package__': None, 'Test': <class '__main__.Test'>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    t=Test()
  File "test.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.aa = __a
NameError: global name '_Test__a' is not defined
```

Is it the case that variable with double underscore cannot be used in class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed - a double underline prefix inside a class code is treated in a special way by the Python compiler - 
at compile time, such variables are name mangled to include the class name as a prefix - 
so that the name `__a` anywhere inside the class `Test` will be changed to `_Test__a`. (remembering that "compile time" is often transparent to the user, and can be taken as "at the time the program is run")

That is a feature meant to allow one to have names that are assessed in methods of a class, and not by its subclasses (not in an automatic form) - a feature that in some other languages is carried out by the "private"  member modifier.

Check the Python class documentation at: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references

Answer (score 1):

[The Python 3 docs say:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private)

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.